# rendering fusionmaps on non flash devices

Tags: fusioncharts

if you know fusionMaps which is a flash based mapping tool. I need to have fusionmaps work on iphone/ipad. Any Idea how do I go about supporting these devices to show fusion Maps?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FusionMaps for JavaScript should be out in the next quarter.